# openGauss installation error reporting app_0bd0ce80, no need to create symbolic link?

Tags: python, open-gauss

openGauss installation error app_0bd0ce80, no need to create symbolic link

The error message when executing the installation script is as follows, how to solve this?

[FAILURE] og01:

Using omm:dbgrp to install database.

Using installation program path : /opt/huawei/install/app_0bd0ce80

$GAUSSHOME points to /opt/huawei/install/app_0bd0ce80, no need to create symbolic link.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/huawei/install/om/script/local/Install.py", line 645, in

```
functionDict[g_opts.action]()
```

File "/opt/huawei/install/om/script/local/Install.py", line 588, in startCluster

```
dn.start(self.time_out)
```

File "/opt/huawei/install/om/script/local/../gspylib/component/Kernel/Kernel.py", line 87, in start

```
+ " Error: Please check the gs_ctl log for "
```

Exception: [GAUSS-51607] : Failed to start instance. Error: Please check the gs_ctl log for failure details.

Answer (score 0):

View the log, because of memory overflow, turn up the opengauss,

```
s_install \
-X /opt/software/openGauss/clusterconfig.xml \
-l /home/omm/gs_install.log \
--gsinit-parameter="--encoding=UTF8" \
--dn-guc="max_connections=10" \
--dn-guc="max_process_memory=2GB" \
--dn-guc="shared_buffers=128MB" \
--dn-guc="bulk_write_ring_size=128MB" \
--dn-guc="cstore_buffers=16MB" \
--autostart=yes
```